# Python and GStreamer: Videoconference app

Tags: python, linux, gstreamer-1.0, video-conferencing, python-gstreamer

I really need help, I need to do a videoconference app using python and gstreamer. I'm really lost on how to do it. I tried doing the following code:

```
# coding=utf-8
import gi,sys
gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
from gi.repository import Gst,GLib

################## EMISOR ##################

def x264_send(pipeline,rtpbin, ip, pvo, pao, pvd, pad):
    video = Gst.ElementFactory.make('v4l2src')
    video.set_property('device','/dev/video0')
    pipeline.add(video)
    convert = Gst.ElementFactory.make('videoconvert')
    pipeline.add(convert)
    rate = Gst.ElementFactory.make('videorate')
    pipeline.add(rate)
    
    filter = Gst.ElementFactory.make('capsfilter')
    caps = Gst.Caps.from_string('video/x-raw,width=640,height=480,framerate=25/1,format=I420')
    
    filter.set_property('caps',caps)
    pipeline.add(filter)
    
    x264 = Gst.ElementFactory.make('x264enc')
    x264.set_property('speed-preset','ultrafast')
    x264.set_property('tune','zerolatency')
    x264.set_property('bitrate',2000)
    x264.set_property('key-int-max',25)
    pipeline.add(x264)
    
    h264pay = Gst.ElementFactory.make('rtph264pay')
    h264pay.set_property('pt',96)
    h264pay.set_property('config-interval',1)
    pipeline.add(h264pay)
    queue = Gst.ElementFactory.make('queue')
    
    pipeline.add(queue)
    
    rtp = Gst.ElementFactory.make('udpsink')
    rtp.set_property('host',ip)
    rtp.set_property('port',pvd)
    pipeline.add(rtp)
    
    rtcp = Gst.ElementFactory.make('udpsink')
    rtcp.set_property('host',ip)
    rtcp.set_property('port',pad)
    rtcp.set_property('sync','false')
    rtcp.set_property('async','false')
    pipeline.add(rtcp)
    
    l1 = video.link(convert)
    l2 = convert.link(rate)
    l4 = rate.link(filter)
    l5 = filter.link(x264)
    l6 = x264.link(h264pay)
    l7 = h264pay.link(queue)
    l8 = queue.link_pads('src',rtpbin,'send_rtp_sink_0')
    l9 = rtpbin.link_pads('send_rtp_src_0',rtp,'sink')
    l10 = rtpbin.link_pads('send_rtcp_src_0',rtcp,'sink')
    
    return l1 and l2 and l3 and l4 and l5 and l6 and l7 and l8 and l9 and l10


def aac_send(pipeline,rtpbin, ip, pvo, pao, pvd, pad):
    audio = Gst.ElementFactory.make('autoaudiosrc')
    pipeline.add(audio)
    
    filter = Gst.ElementFactory.make('capsfilter')
    caps = Gst.Caps.from_string('audio/x-raw,format=F32LE,channels=2,rate=48000')
    filter.set_property('caps',caps)
    pipeline.add(filter)
    
    convert = Gst.ElementFactory.make('audioconvert')
    pipeline.add(convert)
    
    aac = Gst.ElementFactory.make('avenc_aac')
    aac.set_property('bitrate',64000)
    pipeline.add(aac)
    
    mp4apay = Gst.ElementFactory.make('rtpmp4apay')
    mp4apay.set_property('pt',97)
    pipeline.add(mp4apay)
    
    queue = Gst.ElementFactory.make('queue')
    pipeline.add(queue)
    
    rtp = Gst.ElementFactory.make('udpsink')
    rtp.set_property('host',ip)
    rtp.set_property('port',pvd)
    pipeline.add(rtp)
    
    rtcp = Gst.ElementFactory.make('udpsink')
    rtcp.set_property('host',ip)
    rtcp.set_property('port',pad)
    rtcp.set_property('sync','false')
    rtcp.set_property('async','false')
    pipeline.add(rtcp)
    
    l1 = audio.link(filter)
    l2 = filter.link(convert)
    l3 = convert.link(aac)
    l4 = aac.link(mp4apay)
    l5 = mp4apay.link(queue)
    l6 = queue.link_pads('src',rtpbin,'send_rtp_sink_1')
    l7 = rtpbin.link_pads('send_rtp_src_1',rtp,'sink')
    l8 = rtpbin.link_pads('send_rtcp_src_1',rtcp,'sink')
    
    return l1 and l2 and l3 and l4 and l5 and l6 and l7 and l8


def rtcp_recv(pipeline,rtpbin, pvo, pao, pvd, pad):
    src1 = Gst.ElementFactory.make('udpsrc')
    src1.set_property('port',5005)
    pipeline.add(src1)
    
    src2 = Gst.ElementFactory.make('udpsrc')
    src2.set_property('port',5007)
    pipeline.add(src2)
    
    l1 = src1.link_pads('src',rtpbin,'recv_rtcp_sink_0')
    l2 = src2.link_pads('src',rtpbin,'recv_rtcp_sink_1')
    
    return l1 and l2

################## RECEPTOR ##################

def on_pad_added(rtpbin, pad, pipeline):
    name = pad.get_name()
    depay = None
    
    if name.startswith('recv_rtp_src_0'):
        # Sesion de video
        depay = pipeline.get_by_name('rtph264depay')
        rtcp = Gst.ElementFactory.make('udpsink')
        rtcp.set_property('host',ip)
        rtcp.set_property('port',5005)
        rtcp.set_property('sync','false')
        rtcp.set_property('async','false')
        pipeline.add(rtcp)
        rtpbin.link_pads('send_rtcp_src_0',rtcp,'sink')
        
    elif name.startswith('recv_rtp_src_1'):
        # Sesión de audio
        depay = pipeline.get_by_name('rtpmp4adepay')
        rtcp = Gst.ElementFactory.make('udpsink')
        rtcp.set_property('host',ip)
        rtcp.set_property('port',5007)
        rtcp.set_property('sync','false')
        rtcp.set_property('async','false')
        pipeline.add(rtcp)
        rtpbin.link_pads('send_rtcp_src_1',rtcp,'sink')
        
    if depay:
        pad_sink = depay.sinkpads[0]
        pad.link(pad_sink)


def h264_recv(pipeline,rtpbin):
    udpsrc = Gst.ElementFactory.make('udpsrc')
    udpsrc.set_property('port',5000)
    caps = Gst.Caps.from_string('application/x-rtp,media=video,clock-rate=90000,encoding-name=H264')
    udpsrc.set_property('caps',caps)
    pipeline.add(udpsrc)
    
    rtph264depay = Gst.ElementFactory.make('rtph264depay','rtph264depay')
    pipeline.add(rtph264depay)
    
    queue = Gst.ElementFactory.make('queue')
    pipeline.add(queue)
    
    avdec_h264 = Gst.ElementFactory.make('avdec_h264')
    pipeline.add(avdec_h264)
    
    videoconvert = Gst.ElementFactory.make('videoconvert')
    pipeline.add(videoconvert)
    
    autovideosink = Gst.ElementFactory.make('autovideosink')
    pipeline.add(autovideosink)
    
    l1 = udpsrc.link_pads('src',rtpbin,'recv_rtp_sink_0')
    l2 = rtph264depay.link(queue)
    l3 = queue.link(avdec_h264)
    l4 = avdec_h264.link(videoconvert)
    l5 = videoconvert.link(autovideosink)
    
    return l1 and l2 and l3 and l4 and l5


def aac_recv(pipeline,rtpbin):
    udpsrc = Gst.ElementFactory.make('udpsrc')
    udpsrc.set_property('port',5002)
    caps = Gst.Caps.from_string('application/x-rtp,media=audio,encoding-name=MP4A-LATM,clock-rate=48000,config=40002320adca00')
    udpsrc.set_property('caps',caps)
    pipeline.add(udpsrc)
    
    rtpmp4adepay = Gst.ElementFactory.make('rtpmp4adepay','rtpmp4adepay')
    pipeline.add(rtpmp4adepay)
    
    queue = Gst.ElementFactory.make('queue')
    pipeline.add(queue)
    
    avdec_aac = Gst.ElementFactory.make('avdec_aac')
    pipeline.add(avdec_aac)
    
    audioconvert = Gst.ElementFactory.make('audioconvert')
    pipeline.add(audioconvert)
    
    autoaudiosink = Gst.ElementFactory.make('autoaudiosink')
    pipeline.add(autoaudiosink)
    
    l1 = udpsrc.link_pads('src',rtpbin,'recv_rtp_sink_1')
    l2 = rtpmp4adepay.link(queue)
    l3 = queue.link(avdec_aac)
    l4 = avdec_aac.link(audioconvert)
    l5 = audioconvert.link(autoaudiosink)
    
    return l1 and l2 and l3 and l4 and l5


def rtcp_recv(pipeline,rtpbin):
    src1 = Gst.ElementFactory.make('udpsrc')
    src1.set_property('port',5001)
    pipeline.add(src1)
    
    src2 = Gst.ElementFactory.make('udpsrc')
    src2.set_property('port',5003)
    pipeline.add(src2)
    
    l1 = src1.link_pads('src',rtpbin,'recv_rtcp_sink_0')
    l2 = src2.link_pads('src',rtpbin,'recv_rtcp_sink_1')
    
    return l1 and l2

################## MAIN ##################

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Gst.init(sys.argv)
    
    if len(sys.argv) > 6:
        print('Uso del comando: vcall.py puerto_Origen_Video puerto_Origen_Audio puerto_Destino_Video puerto_Destino_Audio\n\tLos parámetros son opcionales.')
        sys.exit()
    else: ####### HACER CON BUCLE for i in range(len(sys.argv)
    
        ## Puerto Video Origen (PVO)
        try:
            pvo = sys.argv[1]
        except IndexError:
            pvo = 5000
 
        pvoRTCP = pvo + 1
 
        ## Puerto Audio Origen (PAO)
        try:
            pao = sys.argv[2]
        except IndexError:
            pao = 5002

        paoRTCP = pao + 1

        ## Puerto Video Destino (PVD)
        try:
            pvd = sys.argv[3]
        except IndexError:
            pvd = 5004

        pvdRTCP = pvd + 1


        ## Puerto Audio Destino (PAD)
        try:
            pao = sys.argv[4]
        except IndexError:
            pao = 5006

        padRTCP = pad + 1

        ## IP destino
        try:
            ip = sys.argv[5]
        except IndexError:
            ip = '192.168.0.3'
    
    pipelineEmisor = Gst.Pipeline.new("pipeline")
    pipelineReceptor = Gst.Pipeline.new("pipeline")
    rtpbinEmisor = Gst.ElementFactory.make('rtpbin')
    rtpbinReceptor = Gst.ElementFactory.make('rtpbin')
    pipelineEmisor.add(rtpbinEmisor)
    rtpbinReceptor.connect('pad-added', on_pad_added, pipelineReceptor)
    pipelineReceptor.add(rtpbinReceptor)
    
    r1 = x264_send(pipelineEmisor,rtpbinEmisor,ip,pvo,pao,pvd,pad)
    r2 = aac_send(pipelineEmisor,rtpbinEmisor,ip,pvo,pao,pvd,pad)
    r3 = rtcp_recv(pipelineEmisor,rtpbinEmisor,ip,pvo,pao,pvd,pad)
    
    r4 = h264_recv(pipelineReceptor,rtpbinReceptor,ip,pvo,pao,pvd,pad)
    r5 = aac_recv(pipelineReceptor,rtpbinReceptor,ip,pvo,pao,pvd,pad)
    r6 = rtcp_recv(pipelineReceptor,rtpbinReceptor,ip,pvo,pao,pvd,pad)
    
    if r1 and r2 and r3 and r4 and r5 and r6:
        pipelineEmisor.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
        loop = GLib.MainLoop()
        try:
            loop.run()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            pass
        pipelineEmisor.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
```

Can anyone help me?

I really need this done and, as I said, I'm really lost.

The program needs to have the following specifications:

*By command line it will allow the indication of the following arguments:*

*• Local peer port for video reception*.

*• Local peer port for audio reception.*

*• Port for video reception destination.*

*• Port for audio reception destination.*

*• Destination IP address.*

*The RTCP ports will be the corresponding odd ports.*

*The captured images will have the following characteristics:*

*• 640x480 pixels.*

*• 25 frames per second.*

*The captured audio will have the following characteristics:*

*• 48000 samples per second.*

*• Stereo.*

*• Sample in F32LE format.*

*The video codec would be H264 with a constant bitrate of 2 Mbps and a key frame per second.*

*The audio codec will be AAC, and will transmit at a constant rate of 64 Kbps.*

¿Do I have to make a program for the transmitter and another program for the receiver or can I do it all in just one program?
Another question is, what am I doing wrong, I can't see anything when I execute the program.

Thank you very much beforehand.

Comment: It would be useful if you describe what are the issues with the code as you written it. Usually people will not be able to help in writing your program for you, but can help answering more specific questions on what is not working and why.

Comment: Ok, sorry, the main problem is: ¿do I have to make a program for the transmitter and another program for the receiver or can I do it all in just one program? Another question is, what am I doing wrong, I can't see anything when I execute the program.

Comment: When using Gstreamer, the first line of troubleshooting is activating debug traces. Please share the output of running your app with at least `GST_DEBUG=2 ./app.py`.

Comment: Also, the code doesn't execute due to programming errors. Can you share a clean version?

Comment: Having only ever used Gstreamer for playing files, I'm no expert but logically, it makes sense for the code to at least have a `mode` i.e. it is either in transmit or receive mode. That could be split into two programs or contained within one but with a decision made at the start. As with all things in real life, there is no right or wrong, if it works as intended.